# Java - Stack JLabels with image on top of one another and enable mouse action

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm building a Klondike solitaire game with Java. It can be seen on the piles that the cards stack themselves on top of each other. The layout is null so I'm using absolute positioning, and just stacking the labels with image is not that hard.

However, I don't know how to implement the click actions for the stacked cards. Every card in the stacked cards has to be clickable, yet ones except the top card can only be clicked when its top part is clicked. How do I implement this?

Comment: First, consider using a `JLayeredPane`, it will make managing the z-order easier. Then beyond that, you kind of don't care, as the `MouseEvent` will stop at the highest component clicked on

Comment: Oh thank you, I just figured that out